# Ubuntu 17.10 did not install correctly after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.10 but now my Ubuntu does not look like Ubuntu 17.10 at all! I know probably some packages are missed during installation, but I was wondering how can I fix this problem?

For instance, I can not see the calendar in the middle upper part of my screen. Or the way I should close a window is like before (In new Ubuntu 17.10 you should be able to close the windows like in Windows from the right side of the window), etc.

[image]

I tried a lot of suggestions, but none of them worked.
What should I do to have a complete Ubuntu 17.10?

After I restart my computer, I have two options to login:

1. Unity
2. Ubuntu Xorg

I only can log in with the first option. Ubuntu Xorg does not work for me.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "my Ubuntu does not look like Ubuntu 17.10". Maybe a screenshot may help.

Comment: For instance, I can not see the calendar in the middle upper part of my screen. Or the way I should close a window is like before (In new Ubuntu 17.10 you should be able to close the windows like windows from the right side of the window) and etc.....